# data which should be exposed trough whole mvc4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

If I want to put combobox with some values inside _Layout.cshtml to be exposed accross whole application where should I put this data combobox data? inside global.asax file or is there better approach having performance in mind?

Comment: i think you just put it in shared file (layout or that you are refering as master layout view)

Answer (score 0):

If the values are mostly static and you could just code them directly in the control then you could either

- Add the control directly to your _Layout.cshtml
- Create a partial view, put your control in there, and add the control to your _layout.cshtml

In either case the values would be in the control.

Or if the values need to come from a service or some other settings (can't/shouldn't be coded directly in the control) then you could create a controller (or add an action to an existing one) and call that controller from your _layout. You can do that with `Html.Action()`.

Then in that controller you can get the values from wherever they are. The question asked where you should put them, but it doesn't mention where they come from. In either case I would just have an interface like `IThingsThatGoIntheComboBoxProvider` or `IFooProvider`, inject that into the controller, and get the values from that. The implementation could be a WCF service, a class that reads from web.config, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The approach we usually take with content that is present in all pages (maybe a footer or header) is to put the markup in the layout file and then have all our models inherit from a base model, which will hold the shared data and have all our controllers inherit from a base controller, which fills the shared part of the model with the relevant data.

This way the handling of shared elements on the page is abstracted away from developers working on a specific page.